# How to create mongoDB user using Powershell?

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to write a script that creates a user in the `admin` database of a mongoDB 3.0 replica set.

After much reading and many tries using different versions of the c-sharp MongoDB drivers, I was finally able to put together the following code, which is able to log successfully into the replica set, access the `admin` database, writing out the full name of the `system` collection:

```
try {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
    Add-Type -Path 'E:\drivers\MongoDB-CSharpDriver-2.0.2\MongoDB.Driver.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'E:\drivers\MongoDB-CSharpDriver-2.0.2\MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll'
    Add-Type -Path 'E:\drivers\MongoDB-CSharpDriver-2.0.2\MongoDB.Bson.dll'

    $connectionString = "mongodb://username:password@primary:27017,secondary:27017,arbiter:27017/admin?replicaSet=name&authSource=admin"
    $dbName =  "admin"
    $collectionName =  "System"

    function Get-MongoDBDatabase ($connectionString, $db) {
        $mongoClient = New-Object MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient($connectionString)
        $mongoServer = $mongoClient.GetServer()
        $mongoServer.GetDatabase($db)
    }

    [MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabase] $mongoDatabase = Get-MongoDBDatabase $connectionString $dbName
    [MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection] $mongoCollection = $mongoDatabase.GetCollection($collectionName)

    Write-Output "Test accessing collection: $($mongoCollection.FullName)"
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" 
}
```

At this point I have no clue in which direction to move to create a new user in the `admin` database and assign this user some roles.

```
db.createUser( 
   { 
     user: "testUser", 
     pwd: "abc123", 
     roles: [  
        {role:"read", db:"admin"},  
        {role:"readWrite", db:"databaseOne"}, 
        {role:"readWrite", db:"databaseTwo"}, 
        {role:"readWrite", db:"databaseThree"}, 
        {role:"readWrite", db:"databaseFour"}, 
        {role:"read", db:"config"}] 
   } 
)
```

Above is the command/query that I would like to be able to execute on the `admin` database, but I need your help to understand how to translate this into Powershell using the MongoDB C-Sharp Driver v.2.0.2

Comment: That driver version is very old, you should update to the latest.

Comment: If I do, @PeteGarafano , then I get into generics and for some reason I haven't yet found working code that is able to achieve just what the above code does - let alone creating a user!

Comment: @PeteGarafano I decided to follow your suggestion - please see my solution below

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a way to make this work, alas not entirely in Powershell.

Following @PeteGarafano suggestion I decided to use the latest and greatest driver (version 2.4.3.23, downloaded via NuGet) in a simple Visual Studio class library.

Since this is just a test at the moment the code is very crude and full of hard-coded things (for example the roles to be assigned to the user)

Here is the code of the class library:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace MongoDBUtilities
{
    public class Connectivity
    {
        public bool DoesUserExist(string connectionString, string databaseName, string username)
        {
            try
            {
                var command = @" { usersInfo: { user: '" + username + @"', db: 'admin' } } ";

                var result = runCommand(connectionString, databaseName, command);
                var users = result["users"];
                if(users != null) 
                {
                    var usersArray = users.AsBsonArray;
                    if(usersArray.Count > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public string CreateUser(string connectionString, string databaseName, string username, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var command = @"{ 
                      createUser: '" + username + @"',
                      pwd: '" + password + @"',
                      roles: [
                          { role: 'read', db: 'admin'},  
                          { role: 'read', db: 'someDB'},  
                          { role: 'read', db: 'someOtherDB'}] 
                    }";

                var result = runCommand(connectionString, databaseName, command);
                return result.ToJson().ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                return unfoldException(ex);
            }
        }

        private BsonDocument runCommand(string connectionString, string databaseName, string command)
        {
            var database = getDatabase(connectionString, databaseName);
            var task = database.RunCommandAsync<BsonDocument>(command);
            var result = task.Result;
            return result;
        }

        private IMongoDatabase getDatabase(string connectionString, string databaseName) {
            IMongoClient client;
            client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            return client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        }

        private string unfoldException(Exception ex) {
            string message = ex.Message + Environment.NewLine;
            Exception currentException = ex;
            while (currentException.InnerException != null)
            {
                currentException = currentException.InnerException;
                message += currentException.Message + Environment.NewLine;
            }
            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing fancy, really, but the main point is how **you can use the JSON form of any command** as described in the **MongoDB official reference documentation** (for example: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/usersInfo/).

**NOTE**: *There is another way to do this, building* `BsonDocument` *objects, but I found it less intuitive since the reference uses all JSON syntax.*

Next, I used this library in my PS script. Here is an example:

```
try {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
    Add-Type -Path 'E:\drivers\MongoDB\MongoDBUtilities.dll'

    $connectionString = "mongodb://username:password@primaryServerName:27017,secondaryServerName:27017,arbiterServerName:27017/admin?replicaSet=replicaSetName&authSource=admin"
    $conn = New-Object -TypeName MongoDBUtilities.Connectivity
    if($conn.DoesUserExist($connectionString, "admin", "testUser")) {
        Write-Output "User already exists, no need to create again"
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "Creating user...";
        $result = $conn.CreateUser($connectionString, "admin", "testUser", "test")
        Write-Output $result;
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" 
}
```

This example first checks if a user is already in the `admin` database and, if it is not already there, it creates it.

I hope this can be useful for anyone trying to do anything similar, either in C# or in Powershell.